# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'queue_ref'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to read a CSV file using Tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read("../input/training.csv")
```

However, I get this issue on the last line of the code:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py in read(self, queue, name)
    191       queue_ref = queue
    192     else:
--> 193       queue_ref = queue.queue_ref
    194     if self._reader_ref.dtype == dtypes.resource:
    195       return gen_io_ops._reader_read_v2(self._reader_ref, queue_ref, name=name)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'queue_ref'
```

Any idea what could be the cause of this?

Comment: `reader.read()` doesn't take a filename. From the documentation it takes a *queue*: *queue: A Queue or a mutable string Tensor representing a handle to a Queue, with string work items.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a *queue* for your files:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["../input/training.csv"])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
```

From the [`tf.TextLineReader().read()` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TextLineReader):

> ```
> read(
>       queue,
>       name=None
>   )
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> - **`queue`**: A Queue or a mutable string Tensor representing a handle to a Queue, with string work items.

and from the [*Reading from files* section](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data#Reading_from_files) of the API guide:

> A typical pipeline for reading records from files has the following stages:
>
> 1. The list of filenames
> 2. *Optional* filename shuffling
> 3. *Optional* epoch limit
> 4. Filename queue
> 5. A Reader for the file format
> 6. A decoder for a record read by the reader
> 7. *Optional* preprocessing
> 8. Example queue

The `tf.train.string_input_producer()` call above creates the filename queue from item 4, passing in a simple list of filenames (item 1). The `tf.TextLineReader()` is item 5 on the above list.

Comment: Thank you! Also, do you know how to read multiple files with using that queue? I mean also `test.csv`, `labels.csv`.

Comment: @octavian: the queue takes a list of filenames, just add more to that list.

Comment: This line seems to get keys and values for all the files in the queue `key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)` . Do you know how to separate the keys and the values by the file from which they were read?

Comment: @octavian: each `read()` call produces a single line; the key reflects what the source of that line was. So if you have multiple files, the key *changes* when the value comes from a different file.